# I got a warning about deleting a question with answers even though I'd deleted my answer

Tags: support

I got this warning when I tried to delete:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Even though I'd already deleted the answer.

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?